# Getting multiple errors when typing "npm start" in bash terminal

Tags: json, npm

**These are the errors I'm receiving when typing "npm start" into my bash terminal:**

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! file /Users/nickperry/Desktop/NucampFolder/git-test/package.json

npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json

npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token } in JSON at position 234 while parsing near '...": "lite-server",

npm ERR! JSON.parse   },

npm ERR! JSON.parse   "repository": {...'

npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.

npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/nickperry/.npm/_logs/2019-11-15T17_16_58_597Z-debug.log
```

**Here are the contents of my package.json folder:**

```
    {
  "name": "git-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Git and NPM",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "lite": "lite-server",
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/NickPurry/git-test.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/NickPurry/git-test/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/NickPurry/git-test#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: please post the contents of the package.json file

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have an additional comma on line 234. You can't have one at the end of the last element in an array.

Comment: Christ, I figured it out.  I had an extra comma after "lite-server".  Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike JavaScript Object Literal, JSON doesn't need comma after the last name-value par of a object. So you need to remove the comma after the name-value par `"lite": "lite-server"`

Use this:

```
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "npm run lite",
        "lite": "lite-server"
    }
```